# Trigger transition to 'loading' route after ember-simple-auth authentication

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'd like to display a "loading..." animation to the users logging into my application.

Ember automatically transitions to a 'loading' route (if any) if a model returns a promise, so it gives the opportunity to display a 'loading' template till the server responds.

Now, I have a login form where submit triggers the 'authenticate' action in my controller (which is defined in the LoginControllerMixin).
This seems not to be recognised as a promise by ember, hence the application does not transition to the 'loading' route.

Maybe there is a way around this using simple-auth session state, but I can't figure it out

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the loading routes only work nicely when there's a transition and the framework is waiting for the promise returned by the destination route's `model` hook to resolve. That's not the case with Ember Simple Auth's LoginControllerMixin's `authenticate` action though. To display a loading message you can simply override that `authentication` action though:

`export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var _this = this;
      this.set('loading', true);
      this._super().then(function() {
        _this.set('loading', false);
      }, function() {
        _this.set('loading', false);
      });
    }
  }
});`

Comment: I like this approach as I can display a loading message in the login form and not transition to a complete new screen. Login may fail and its nicer to display the failure message before leaving the form. I think that, since password is cleared, not showing any message gives a bit of uncertainty to the user even if the login takes only a second.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it isn't a promise, it's that it isn't part of a transition.  If you want to modify the authentication mixin, you can have it manually transition to a loading route, then begin the promise, then transition to destination post authentication.  Honestly, I'd be surprised if this is worth it, unless your back-end authenticates really slow.

You would change the authentication logic to something like this:

```
this.transitionTo('loading').then(function(){      
  authenticateLogicCall().then(function(){
    this.transitionTo('authenticatedResource');
  });
});
```